# Rails 3: How to store screen resolution?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-resolution

I want to store user's screen resolution in database when user login. How to detect and store it to database when user login?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Read it with JavaScript](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=javascript%20get%20window%20size&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=#hl=en&expIds=17259,26428&xhr=t&q=javascript+screen+resolution&cp=19&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=javascript+screen+r&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=19bff151c0ba26e) (browsers don't send screen resolution information by default, so it isn't available to Ruby or anything else server side unless you make it so), then [generate a hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement), set the name and value based on the data you've gathered, then [add it to the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) containing the username and password inputs.

Oh, and you might find the window size more useful than the screen resolution. Not everybody maximizes their windows.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to measure window size instead of screen resolution.